# Event triggered after writing in a combobox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I want to modify the Items of a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` after changing the text of the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.

I'm casting the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` to a `ComboBox` during the `EditingControlShowing`, so I can change the `ComboBoxStyle` to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`.

Then after a key is pressed I want to change the Items list according to the new text, the problem is with the key pressed Events, the text remains the same, so I have to parse the key input, depending on the type of key entered, if it's a deleting key, or if there is a shift pressed, etc. So I would prefer to use an event triggered after this text is changed, so I don't have to parse the key pressed.

Which event should I use for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the text in ComboBox changed, you can subscribe to [TextUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.textupdate?view=netcore-3.1) event. It occurs when the combo box text has changed.